# How to list all the inherited tables from the parent table?

Tags: mysql, inheritance

I have `3 tables (janitor, security & manager)` which inherited from the `user table`.
[image]

What is the query can be used to produce the following result(list all the name of the child tables)?
[image]

Thank you. Cheer :)

Comment: you want to produce table names which are references of the user table?

Comment: @EdgarAllanBayron yes :) I hope to produce table names that referencing the user table only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
table_name
FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE table_schema = 'database_name'
AND referenced_table_name = 'user';
```

This will list of referenced tables under table `'user'`.